# change a combobox of images to a formset of inputfile

Tags: python, django

I have some models in my app,every one is going to have a set of images(n images),in order to handle this i designed these models:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
   HeadImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")

class Image(models.Model):
   Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
   Gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='images')
```

now every model to have n images,will have a foreignkey to Gallery,like thie:

```
class Tour(models.Model):
   Category=models.ForeignKey(TourCategory)
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Count=models.SmallIntegerField() 
   PriceUnit=models.ForeignKey(PriceUnit)
   Price=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   Description=models.TextField()
   Status_Choices=(
      ('a',ugettext_lazy('Activate')),
      ('d',ugettext_lazy('Deactivate')),
   )
   StatusType=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=Status_Choices)
   Gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery,editable=False)
   CHOICES=(
      ('T',ugettext_lazy('yes')),
      ('F',ugettext_lazy('no')),
   )
   isSpecial=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=CHOICES)
```

When I add Tour model to admin,I have a combobox for Gallery Field,this combobox doesn't make sense,like this:
[image: add tour in admin]

I don't wanna use other galleries that have been added already,instead I wanna have a formset like this:
[image: add tour form with formset]

Here `Head Image` is `HeadImage` field in `Gallery` model and `Image1,Image2,...` is an `inline Image set` for `Image` model.how can I handle this situation in admin?I wanna ommit that combobox and replace it with this `HeadImage` and `ImageSet`.

thanks in advancce

---

when I change Tour model to this:

```
class Tour(Gallery):
    ...
```

I have some thing like this:

[image]

while I need n images for each Tour,so that `Head Image` is the primary image and more Images(related to Image model) are optional and I'm thinking how to bring a formset of Images beside `Head Image Field` in `Add Tour Form`.
do U have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form you've provided is accurate, 'Tour' doesn't contain a gallery, it *implements* a gallery. Therefore, you'll probably have better luck using Django's [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). Try something like the following:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    head_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='images')

class Tour(Gallery):
    ...
```

And for the love of all that's holy, read the [Python styleguide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Method names should be in lower case with underscores to avoid namespace clashes with classes.